# while start rails server error for sidekiq pro 5

Tags: sidekiq

sidekiq and sidekiqpro integrate in my rails app while start rails server get an error in sidekiqpro web.rb file
below

syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
      rescue Sidekiq::Batch::NoSuchBatch
            ^

Comment: could you provide some more information, like code snippets and more logging?